# I have StartDate and EndDate of current month. I want to compare database records of every date which are in between those two dates

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel

I want to get everydate records of current month and compare every date with created_at column. If records available for particular date then display those records. I have StartDate and EndDate and I want to display records of every day compare with date of each day and then if records available then display. How to do that.I tried with some query. But, it is not working..

```
//Display TAT Reports
public function reports() {

//Each date from current month     
for ($i = 1; $i <= date('t'); $i++) 
{
 $dates[] = date('Y') . "-" . date('m') . "-" . str_pad($i, 2, '0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
 }
$now = Carbon::now();
$monthStartDate = $now->startOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d'); //start date of month
$monthendDate = $now->endOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d'); //enddate of month

$recordsOnMonthlyBasis = DB::table('pickups')->select('tat', 'completed_at')
                            ->whereNotNull('tat')
                            ->whereDate('completed_at', '>=', "$monthStartDate")
                            ->whereDate('completed_at', '<=', "$monthendDate")->get()->toArray();
}
```

if I print `$recordsOnMonthlyBasis` then it will display all records in between Start And End Date. but, I want records of each day to compare with date in DB.

Any help Appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by **"I want records of each day to compare with date in DB"** can you please elaborate with some example.

Comment: @Raka Sure. 
Let's say. I have startDate="01/06/2019" and endDate="30/06/2019". In Database table I have records for 05/06/2019, 07/06/2019,23/06/2019 and so many for other dates.

So, I need to compare the dates which are lying in between start and end date so that I can get the records of 05,07,23 and so on.

Comment: You don't really have a start date of 01/06/2019, do you? One would hope you have a start date of '2019-06-01' !! Incidentally, if this is MySQL, tag it as such, and see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry dude I have start date and end date.. Please check I have used startOfMonth()

Comment: I suggest you provide sample data and a corresponding desired result (like always)

Comment: @Strawberry :-- 
If I print this query:- 
$monthStartDate = $now->startOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d'); //start date of month
Then I am getting "2019-06-01"

Likewise, I am getting endDate also.

Answer (score 0):

You can addon  this query for get daily records.

```
 DB::table('pickups')->where(DB::raw("(DATE_FORMAT(completed_at,'%Y-%m-%d'))"), '=', Carbon::today()->format('Y-m-d'));
```

Comment: Thanx for replay.But, this will compare current day.

Answer (score 0):

Change the query.

```
$now = Carbon::now();
$monthStartDate = $now->startOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d'); //start date of month
$monthendDate = $now->endOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d'); //enddate of month

$recordsOnMonthlyBasis = DB::table('pickups')->select('tat', 'completed_at')
                        ->whereNotNull('tat')
                        ->whereBetween('completed_at',[$monthStartDate,$monthendDate])
                        ->get()->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this,

```
$fromDate1 = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($fromDate);
$toDate1 = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($toDate);

for ($fromDate1; $fromDate1 <= $toDate1; $fromDate1->addDays(1)) {
    // Your code 
}
```

Take your `from date` and loop till `end date` and add one day on each iteration.

Hope it helps :)